MSYS2, clang last version does not appear in pacman query
I decided to build an application from its source. For this purpose clang version 17.0.0 or later is needed. I use MSYS2 on windows 10 and when I run the command pacman --query clang it returns back clang 11.0.0-5. The latest Clang version at the date is 17.0.1. I have installed mingw-w64-x86_64-llvm but Clang version remains at 11.0.0-5. Please help

You almost never want gcc or clang packages, they are cygwin-based. You want mingw-w64-...-clang and mingw-w64-...-gcc. Consult What are MSYS2 environments? How do I pick one?.

And those are kept up-to-date, unlike the cygwin ones.

pacman -S $MINGW_PACKAGE_PREFIX-clang

@David Grayson, thank you. Please make your comment as answer, so I can mark it as solving the problem.

You want to install MinGW clang:
pacman -S $MINGW_PACKAGE_PREFIX-clang

